# Is my ER diagram to relational model correct?

Tags: sql, model, entity-relationship, diagram, relational

I'm just learning datamodels and SQL and so on, and I'm not sure I converted it correctly.

Here's the ER diagram of a library:

[image]

And here's the relational diagram:

[image]

I'm not sure how the "author" table should look. I've read that if there's a multivalued attribute you need to store that in a separate table, but I'm still not sure if that table (or the whole thing) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Each author can write one or more books, and each book can have one or more authors.  So the relationship is many-to-many, and that means you can't record the author's key in the book table (each book could have only one author) or the book's ISBN in the Author table (each author could have only one book).  The only alternative is to record both values in a new table (we could call it AuthorBook).  In this new table, the combination of an author's key and a book's ISBN must be unique, but each individual value can appear multiple times.

The rest of the tables (book, publisher, loan and borrower) and their foreign key constraints look good.